# Node.js socket app on openshift

Tags: node.js, sockets, openshift

I'm trying to deploy a simple node.js socket app on OpenShift.

First I tried setting up the listener as:

```
var server = net.createServer(newSocket); //newSocket is a listener method
var port   = 8888;
server.listen(port);
```

and this causes:

```
Error: listen EACCES
```

Then I researched a bit and learned that you need to listen using `OPENSHIFT_NODEJS` properties and set the listener like this:

```
var server = net.createServer(newSocket);
var ipaddr = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port   = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8888;
server.listen(port, ipaddr);
```

Now the app is started at: `127.6.253.1:8080` - however when I try to telnet it using my OpenShift app url and 8080 I get server timeout.

If you have experience with the similar situation let me know.
The code of the app I'm trying to make it work on OpenShift is at https://github.com/denimf/NodeChat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the `node.js` web hosting services don't support socket listener. I solved my problem by hosting the Node app on a dedicated virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

The internal port for the OpenShift app is 8080, but it is exposed externally on port 80 at the URL specified in your control panel.  You can also see the app URL in the console by doing:

```
echo $OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS
```

Comment: Scott the url that I'm accessing is the same one in the OPENSHIFT_APP_DNS variable the problem is that i can't connect to the socket on neither port 80 or port 8080.